# React Router 6 - How to pass components to Route-path with conditional logic

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am currently updating my React-app from React Router Version 5 to 6 and I can't figure out how to properly refractor one of my routes, which looks as follows:

React Router Version 5:

```
<Route path="/">
  {!authCtx.isLoggedIn && <Login />}
  {authCtx.isLoggedIn && <Layout />}
</Route>
```

What I tried in React Router Version 6:

```
<Route path="/" element={!authCtx.isLoggedIn ? <Login /> : <Layout />} />
```

The routing works in Version 6 (the Login or Layout Components get loaded in the browser, depeneding on whether a user is authenticated or not) but I see the following error messages appearing in the console, which i don't see in Version 5:

- react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:117 Warning: Each child in a
  list should have a unique "key" prop.
- react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Received `true` for a
  non-boolean attribute `exact`.
- Warning: React does not recognize the `activeClassName` prop on a DOM
  element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a
  custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `activeclassname` instead. If
  you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from
  the DOM element.

So my question is: What is the proper way to pass a Component to the element props of a Route in React-Router Version 6, if I want to use some conditional logic, that determines which Component gets passed?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: All those warning appear to be occurring in a `Disclosure` component. Please update your question to include all the relevant code you've an issue with or questions about.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the `!authCtx.isLoggedIn` to some condition, but I assume it'll be something like `!authCtx.isLoggedIn === true/false`

Can you try it like this to see if this works or not, but I hope it does, I'm learning React, too, so maybe I could be wrong, pardon me :)

```
<Route path="/" element={!authCtx.isLoggedIn === true ? <Login /> : <Layout />} />
```

Comment: Don't compare boolean values directly to `true`|`false`, this is an anti-pattern. Nothing at all incorrect with using the boolean value directly in an expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact way how you would conditionally render the component. There is no bug in your rendering. But for the warning of key you need to add an attribute to the child elements whereever you are mapping over a list and assign a unique value to that key attribute for every list item (either an id or the index of element).